# Variable RegEx String Replacement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, sencha-touch

Is there an easy way to use regular expression to find all matching strings, and then use part of the result as the replacement?

For example, consider the following example:

```
tpl: '<a href="{link_url}">{link_html}</a>';
```

Here, I would like to run a simple RegEx to look for any match to the '{string}' pattern, and then use what's between the curly braces as an array key. So, the results from the example would be:

array[link_url] and array[link_html]

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the values of your array to be?

Comment: They actually relate to an array of objects, for example:
buttons: [
    { link_url: 'google.com', link_html: 'Google' },
    { link_url: 'msn.com', link_html: 'MSN' }
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
var map = {link_url: 'msn.com', link_html: 'MSN' };

var str = '<a href="{link_url}">{link_html}</a>';

str = str.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/g, function(m, p1) {
    return map[p1];
});
```

which will return

```
'<a href="msn.com">MSN</a>'
```

**Reference**: [`String.prototoype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: @BenM: You're welcome :) I'm glad it is what you want because I was not 100% sure. Your description was not *that* clear ;)